# Iterate an array of objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

I have an array of objects.

`myArray = [{a:1,b:1,c:1,d:1},{a:2,b:2,c:2,d:2},{a:3,b:3,c:3,d:3},{a:4,b:4,c:4,d:4}]`

I want to create a new dictionary from it:
`newDict = {a:[1,2,3,4],c:[1,2,3,4]}`

I'm totally new to Javascript and Node.js
Any kind of help is highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what's the the rationale to get newDict from myArray? it's not clear at all. I'm quite sure you missed `b:[1,2,3,4], d:[1,2,3,4]`

Comment: what happens to the other properties? what have you tried?

Comment: @DiegoDeVita a: [all values of a], b:[all values of b] ... by values I mean numbers here. That's how I got it

Comment: @NinaScholz I don't want other properties. That's why I've omitted them.

Comment: @SarthakPundir you have an array with objects all having the properties a,b,c,d... but your resulting array just talks about a and c. You were not clear on what's the rule to transform from myArray to newDict and the first guess of everyone here was: group those values by property name.

Comment: @DiegoDeVita I'm sorry for my ambiguous explanation of the problem. I don't want all the properties from the given objects, need only a couple of them. How can that be done?

Comment: you have plenty of answers now but in particular the NinaScholz's one is addressing the subsetting of the result data like you are supposed to have asked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively you can also do it in a for loop, in case you are unfamiliar with the reduce method.

```js
const myArray = [{a:1,b:1,c:1,d:1},{a:2,b:2,c:2,d:2},{a:3,b:3,c:3,d:3},{a:4,b:4,c:4,d:4}]

const wantedProperties = ['a', 'b', 'd']

const mydict = {}
for (const item of myArray) {
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(item)) {
    if (wantedProperties.includes(key)) {
     mydict[key] = (mydict[key] || []).concat(value)
    }
  }
}

console.log(mydict)
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution Vincent but I only need only a few selected properties from the underlying objects, not all of them. How can we achieve that over here?

Comment: You can just move the `mydict[key] = (mydict[key] || []).concat(value)` into an if and check if the `key` is in the properties you want. I updated my answer with an example of that. Is that what your looking for `c` get excluded there.

Answer (score 1):

You basically want to group something. For grouping you can usually use `.reduce()`

On every iteration you iterate over your object entries with `Object.entries()` and then you always check if your previous value already has that key, if yes, you push it, if not, you create a new array and put your value inside of it.

```js
let myArray = [{a:1,b:1,c:1,d:1},{a:2,b:2,c:2,d:2},{a:3,b:3,c:3,d:3},{a:4,b:4,c:4,d:4}]


let result = myArray.reduce((prev, curr) => {
   Object.entries(curr).forEach(([key, value]) => {
      if(prev[key]) {
         prev[key].push(value)
      } else {
         prev[key] = [value]
      }
   })
   return prev;
}, {})


console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let targetArray = [{a:1,b:1,c:1,d:1},{a:2,b:2,c:2,d:2},{a:3,b:3,c:3,d:3},{a:4,b:4,c:4,d:4}]


let result = targetArray.reduce((accc, curr) => {
   Object.entries(curr).forEach(([key, value]) => {
      if(!accc[key]) {
         accc[key] = [value]
      } else {
         accc[key].push(value)
      }
   })
   return accc;
}, {})


console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take an object with wanted properties and iterate the array by checking the keys of the object. If a key is in the result object, push the value.

```js
const
    data = [{ a: 1, b: 1, c: 1, d: 1 }, { a: 2, b: 2, c: 2, d: 2 }, { a: 3, b: 3, c: 3, d: 3 }, { a: 4, b: 4, c: 4, d: 4 }],
    result = data.reduce((r, o) => {
        Object.entries(o).forEach(([k, v]) => {
            if (k in r) r[k].push(v);
        });
        return r;
    }, { a: [], c: [] });

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

One can give keys as params to find the desired result

```js
var myArray = [{ a: 1, b: 1, c: 1, d: 1 }, { a: 2, b: 2, c: 2, d: 2 }, { a: 3, b: 3, c: 3, d: 3 }, { a: 4, b: 4, c: 4, d: 4 }];
function findValues(keysArray) {
    let result = {};
    myArray.forEach((item) => {
        for (var key in item) {
            if (keysArray.includes(key)) {
                if (result[key]) {
                    result[key].push(item[key])
                } else {
                    result[key] = [item[key]];
                }
            }
        }
    });
    return result;
}
console.log(findValues(['a', 'c']));
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create an output object, and iterate over the data
2. For every object get its [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/entries) - this provides us with an array of key/value pairs which we can also iterate over.
3. Assign an empty array to an output object key [if it doesn't exist](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment), then push the corresponding key from the iterated object into it.

```js
const data = [{a:1,b:1,c:1,d:1,z:3},{a:2,b:2,c:2,d:2},{a:3,b:3,c:3,d:3},{a:4,b:4,c:4,d:4,z:12}];

const out = {};

for (const obj of data) {
  const entries = Object.entries(obj);
  for (const [key, value] of entries) {
    out[key] ??= [];
    out[key].push(value);
  };
}

console.log(out);
```